# matlab coder: cannot transpose a matrix that is incorrectly deemed to be 3-D when it should always be 2-D

Tags: mex, matlab-coder

I have a function (with the code given below) that I wish to convert into a MEX file. I am trying to use matlab coder to do so.

```
%% Inputs
dof = 3;
num_divs = 72;

ind_cr =
     0     0
     1     1
     1     2
     2     2
     1     3
     2     3
     3     3

ind_switch =
     1
     1
     1
     0
     1
     0
     0

len_stat_atoms =
           1
          72
        5184
          72
      373248
        5184
          72

num_stat_atoms =
   108
   111
   111
     3
   111
     3
     3

coordFile = 
    [3x1        double]
    [3x1        double]
    [3x72x3     double]
    [3x5184x3   double]
    [3x373248x4 double]

radii_cell = 
    [108x1x3      double]
    [111x72x3     double]
    [111x5184x3   double]
    [  3x72x3     double]
    [111x373248x4 double]
    [  3x5184x4   double]
    [  3x72x4     double]

stat_cell = 
    [3x1x108      double]
    [3x72x111     double]
    [3x5184x111   double]
    [3x72x3       double]
    [3x373248x111 double]
    [3x5184x3     double]
    [3x72x3       double]    


%% Code that calls function
for i = 1:(dof*(dof+1)/2+1)
    %% Load matrices
    radii_mat = radii_cell{i,1};
    stat_mat = stat_cell{i,1};
    if ind_switch(i)
        coordFile_mat = coordFile{ind_cr(i,2)+2};
    end
    %% Call the function
    potential_mat = func_test(i,coordFile_mat,radii_mat,stat_mat,...
        ind_cr,len_stat_atoms,num_stat_atoms,num_coord_atoms,...
        counter,num_divs,dof);
end


%% Function code
function potential_mat = func_test(i,coordFile_mat,radii_mat,stat_mat,...
    ind_cr,len_stat_atoms,num_stat_atoms,num_coord_atoms,...
    counter,num_divs,dof);

potential_mat = zeros(num_coord_atoms,num_divs^dof);
for j = 1:size(coordFile_mat,3)
    %% Compute distances
    a = zeros(3,len_stat_atoms(i));
    a = coordFile_mat(:,1:len_stat_atoms(i),j);

    b = zeros(3,len_stat_atoms(i),num_stat_atoms(i));
    b = repmat(a,[1 1 num_stat_atoms(i)]);

    c = zeros(1,len_stat_atoms(i),num_stat_atoms(i));
    c = sqrt(sum((b - stat_mat).^2,1));

    d = zeros(len_stat_atoms(i),num_stat_atoms(i));
    d = shiftdim(c,1);

    distances = zeros(num_stat_atoms(i),len_stat_atoms(i));
    distances = d';

    %% Compute clashes and potentials
    clashes = distances < radii_mat(:,:,j);
    potentials = zeros(size(distances));
    potentials(clashes) = (1-(distances(clashes)./radii_mat(find(clashes)+numel(clashes)*(j-1))).^6).^2;

    %% Iterate over nodes
    col = ind_cr(i,1); row = ind_cr(i,2);
    if col == 1
        ind_kron = repmat(1:size(potentials,2),[num_divs^(dof-row) 1]);
        potentials = potentials(:,ind_kron(:)');
    elseif row == dof
        vec_repmat = [1 num_divs^(col-1)];
        potentials = repmat(potentials,vec_repmat);
    elseif col > 0
        vec_repmat = [1 num_divs^(col-1)];
        ind_kron = repmat(1:size(potentials,2),[num_divs^(dof-row) 1]);
        potentials = repmat(potentials(:,ind_kron(:)'),vec_repmat);
    else
        potentials = repmat(sum(potentials),[1 num_divs^dof]);
    end
    counter = counter+1;
    potential_mat(counter,:) = sum(potentials,1);
end

end
```

The problem occurs at the second line below, where it throws an error because it cannot transpose an ND matrix.

```
d = shiftdim(c,1);
distances = d';
```

Matlab coder identifies `c` to be of size `1 x :? x :?`, which is correct. The `d = shiftdim(c,1)` line should then yield a 2D matrix of size `:? x :?`, which I then transpose. However, it fails to correctly shift the dimensions of `d`, and gives it a size of `:? x :? x :?`. This then causes the transpose error. How can I resolve this problem? Furthermore, for my own edification, why is matlab coder unable to correctly assign the dimensions of my variables, specifically `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `distances`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs describe this as an [Incompatibility with MATLAB in Determining Size of Variable-Size N-D Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/limitations-with-variable-size-support-for-code-generation.html#br952rj) (`d` is created in a loop, so seems to be variable size):

> For variable-size N-D arrays, the size function can return a different result in generated code than in MATLAB. **In generated code**, size(A) returns a fixed-length output because **it does not drop trailing singleton dimensions** of variable-size N-D arrays. By contrast, size(A) in **MATLAB** returns a variable-length output because it **drops trailing singleton dimensions**.
>
> For example, if the shape of array `A` is `:?x:?x:?` and `size(A,3)==1`, `size(A)` returns:
>
> - Three-element vector in generated code
> - Two-element vector in MATLAB code

The issue addressed in the above documentation pertains to the use of the `size` function.  However, in your case, you just want to be able to transpose.  The workaround is to use `permute`, since the transpose is a general case of `permute`:

```
% after shiftdim:
distances = permute(d,[2 1 3])   % same as d' for 2d array, but handles 3d
```

You could also cut out the `shiftdim` entirely:

```
distances = permute(c,[2 3 1])
```

---

Also, I don't have much experience with Coder, but does it really require all those initializations with `zeros`?  They seem unnecessary.